# Why is this true or false statement not working?

Tags: matlab

I´m working with matlab and retrieving data to a variable from a matrix. Here is my problem:

```
B=busdata(22,11)

B =

    1.3500

B==1.35

ans =

     0
```

I havent been able to figure out whys it not giving the true value to this statement.

Comment: Please tell us the result of `B - 1.35`. This is probably a floating point issue ...

Comment: this may be a floating point issue. What you see as 1.35 on screen (with four significant digits) may not actually be 1.35 - try using `round`.

Comment: Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). And try this: `format long; disp(B);`

Comment: it look like it is indeed a floating point issue this is the result: B-1=-2.2204e-16

Comment: Don't read that, no-one ever actually reads that.  Read this instead: http://floating-point-gui.de/.

Comment: Finally i came up with a good enough solution to my problem 1.35<=B<=1.350001, thanks. i didnt know what was going on...

Comment: I'd like to vote up Oli's comment twice if I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper Matlab way to fix, from the documentation, for a very small `C` that should equal zero but doesn't quite:

> Compare floating-point numbers using a tolerance, tol, instead of ==.

```
tol = eps;
abs(C-0) < tol

ans =

     1
```

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html and click on "Compare Floating-point numbers", and check http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html for information on `eps`